# How to get the last index of a comboBox when size isn't constant?

Tags: c#, winforms

In an input form, I have two drop down boxes. The option selected in the first one determines what options will populate the second one. There will always be a 'Default' option in the last index of the drop down, but the number of items will change, so 'Default' is not always at a constant index. For the other options, I can just use it's index for other stuff without knowing what it was, but if default is selected I need to do a special action.

My current solution is a bit bulky because I have to check for the index I know will be the default for each case.

```
switch( comboBoxOne.SelectedIndex )
{
    case 0:
        if( comboBoxTwo.SelectedIndex == 6 )
            //special action
        break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
        if( comboBoxTwo.SelectedIndex== 4 )
            //special action
        break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
        if( comboBoxTwo.SelectedIndex== 5 )
            //special action
        break;
}
```

I can't use comboBoxTwo.MaxDropDownHeight because that's just a limit for how many items you can potentially have.

NOTE**
I can't set 'Default' to index 0 because it causes the other indices to be wrong, so I'd have to do more work mapping them to the correct index. Also, the way the second options are populated is complicated (there's actually 50 different cases) so default is always appended to the last index. How can I get the last valid item index from a comboBox?

Comment: You can populate a CBO (and many other things) with *objects*.  In this case the `SelectedObject` could include information related to what action to take and which options to enable or disable elsewhere

Comment: That could work except I only need to specify an action for the last object in a list of potentially hundreds. Kind of a waste of memory/code.

Comment: wouldn't you just do `combobox.selectedindex = combobox.items.count-1`

Comment: @CharlesMay that is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ComboBox` control has an `Items` collection, which has a `Count` property. So the last item would be at the index one less than the count (since indexes are zero-based):

```
// Select the last item in the combobox
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.Items.Count - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's actually pretty simple...

Something like this shoudl work :

```
if (ComboBox1.GetItemText(this.ComboBox1.SelectedItem)) == "Default")
 {

  ///Your code goes here

 };
```

Comment: Good suggestion, would normally work, except in this (somewhat bizarre) project, there is potential for there to be another 'Default' further up the list but require different actions from the bottom 'Default'. 'Default' is not what the actual option is called I'm using the name for simplicity.

Comment: @Jedediah, just change `Default` with whatever text you want, i guess?